# Eu estou tentando jogar os valores do array "arquivos_b64" no textarea mas não consigo. No console.log os valores são apresentados

Tags: javascript, file-upload

```js
(function() {
  var fileCatcher = document.getElementById('file-catcher');
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
  var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('file-list-display');
  var arquivos_b64 = [];
  var fileList = [],
    renderFileList, sendFile, compactar;

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(evnt) {

    fileList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {

      fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
    }

    renderFileList();

  });

  renderFileList = function() {

    arquivos_b64 = [];

    fileList.forEach(function(file) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');

        arquivos_b64.push(b64); 
        console.log(arquivos_b64);


      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    console.log(arquivos_b64);
    document.getElementById('anxUpload').value = arquivos_b64;

  };

})();
```

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<input id='file-input' type='file' multiple />
<div id='file-list-display'></div>
<textarea id="anxUpload" name="anxUpload" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que vc está usando uma função assíncrona (onloadend). Este código no final:

```
 document.getElementById('anxUpload').value = arquivos_b64;
```

é executado logo imediatamente assim que o script roda e arquivos_b64 ainda está vazio. 
Entenda que o ciclo for dispara a função assíncrona. E continua rodando até o final. Então a função principal conclui e só depois que a função assíncrona vai retornar da execução.
Aí quando a função assíncrona finalmente conclui, ela só roda o código dela que é onde estão os dados que vc quer colocar no textarea.
Então é só passar o código onde vc seta o valor na textarea para dentro da função asíncrona. Assim:

```js
(function() {
  var fileCatcher = document.getElementById('file-catcher');
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
  var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('file-list-display');
  var arquivos_b64 = [];
  var fileList = [],
    renderFileList, sendFile, compactar;

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(evnt) {

    fileList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {

      fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
    }

    renderFileList();

  });

  renderFileList = function() {

    arquivos_b64 = [];

    fileList.forEach(function(file) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');

        arquivos_b64.push(b64); 
        document.getElementById('anxUpload').value = arquivos_b64;

      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

  };

})();
```

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<input id='file-input' type='file' multiple />
<div id='file-list-display'></div>
<textarea id="anxUpload" name="anxUpload" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sensacional!! Deu certo!! Valeu!!